# Terraform: Create block only if variable matches certain values

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create a module that creates interconnect-attachments, but some parts are only  defined if the attachment is using ipsec encryption and if it's not, that block must not exist in the resource else it causes an error (even if it only contains a value set to null.)
I've tried using a dynamic, but I can't quite get the layout right to have it work:

```
resource "google_compute_interconnect_attachment" "interconnect-attachment" {
  project                  = var.project
  region                   = var.region
  name                     = var.name
  edge_availability_domain = var.availability_domain
  type                     = var.type
  router                   = google_compute_router.router.name
  encryption               = var.encryption
  dynamic "ipsec_internal_addresses" {
    for_each = var.encryption != "IPSEC" ? [] : [1]
    content {
      var.address
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially, if var.encryption is set to IPSEC then i want the following block included:

```
  ipsec_internal_addresses = [
    var.address,
  ]
```

The other issue is it appears a dynamic block expects some kind of assignment to happen, but the terraform examples just have the value inside the `ipsec_internal_addresses` so I'm unsure how to to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ipsec_internal_addresses` is not a block in the `google_compute_interconnect_attachment` resource. It is an argument. Therefore, you can use the normal pattern for specifying optional arguments where the conditional returns a `null` type if you do not want to specify a value. Using your conditional and variables:

```
ipsec_internal_addresses = var.encryption == "IPSEC" ? [var.address] : null
```

which will return and assign your `[var.address]` to `ipsec_internal_addresses` when `var.encryption` equals the string `IPSEC`. Otherwise, it will return `null` and the `ipsec_internal_addresses` argument will be ignored.

Comment: I will give this a try, but I tried passing through ipsec_internal_addresses = var.address as null, and it gave me the error. Thanks :L)

Comment: And that does in fact work - thanks. I guess the difference is I was previously passing the null value, inside the argument, where as your solution simply isn't creating the argument at all?

Comment: @djsmiley2kStaysInside I am not sure what your attempt with `null` may have been, but its type restricts its usage to values for arguments. Anything else would likely cause a syntax error.